# Textarea enter keypress not working because of form submit enter prevention

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form in which I've used the following code to prevent the form being submitted on the press of 'Enter'.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

As a result, the 'Enter' key is not working in any textarea input. I can't enter a new line because of the body function. How do I solve this?

```
<textarea name='description' placeholder="Any other information (optional)"</textarea>
```

Comment: try this : http://jsfiddle.net/scraaappy/bfwvc3ya/

Comment: Why would you do that? (catch the 13 key that is)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have find solution.

You prevent enter key on all the form element. Just add some tweak to your code and its done. Just skip prevention of enter key when your focus is on textarea. See below code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event){
      if(event.target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA') {
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
          event.preventDefault();
          return false;
        }
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: It worked. What does tagName call? And why is it in uppercase?

Comment: TagName return name of element in capital latter from which your keydown event was fired.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the form from submitting, try this instead:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
}
```