# Enter doesn't work in text field

Tags: html

I have pretty much the same problem like in this question ( [Textarea enter keypress not working because of form submit enter prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985589/textarea-enter-keypress-not-working-because-of-form-submit-enter-prevention) ) but my code looks totally different.

My script is from ReusableForms. I believe I found the lines

```
$('#reused_form').submit(function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();

    $form = $(this);
    //show some response on the button
    $('button[type="submit"]', $form).each(function()
    {
        $btn = $(this);
        $btn.prop('type','button' ); 
        $btn.prop('orig_label',$btn.text());
        $btn.text('Sendet ...');
    });


                $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'handler.php',
            data: $form.serialize(),
            success: after_form_submitted,
            dataType: 'json' 
        });        

  });
```

... would anybody please be so kind to tell me what to change here so enter works again? I am clueless!

Comment: The code you show is run AFTER the form is submitted. It's too late to change the way Enter key Works.

Comment: Do you mean that pressing enter does not make a new line? If so, please provide your HTML code.

Comment: yes James - that's the Problem. Here's the html code of the form

How dow I do this here - don't have that many characters

Comment: ok let's see if this works .. I'll copy the beginning and the end of the code:

`<form role="form" method="post" id="reused_form" >
                     <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6 form-group g-mb-20">
                       <label class="g-color-gray-dark-v2 g-font-size-13" for="vorname"> Vorname:</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control g-color-black g-bg-white g-bg-white--focus g-brd-gray-light-v4 g-brd-primary--focus rounded-3 g-py-13 g-px-15" id="vorname" name="vorname" required maxlength="50">
</div>`

Comment: `blablabla </label></div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn u-btn-primary g-font-weight-600 g-font-size-13 text-uppercase rounded-3 g-py-12 g-px-35 pull-right" id="btnContactUs">Senden</button>
                    </form>
`

Comment: Try to press 'EDit' the post and then paste you html in the edited post

Answer (score 0):

Based on my observation you are probably using the **input tag** and want to use the **enter key** to **submit** the form or create **multiple rows** in the input box. I would provide solutions for both because I do not know which one you are referring to.

If you want to **create multiple rows** in your the input box when you press enter, **replace** the **input tag** for the **input box** with the **text area tag**:

```
<textarea rows="2"></textarea>
```

> **Change the number in the rows property to specify the amount of rows
>   you want to create.**

If you want to **submit the form** when you press the **enter key**:

```
<textarea rows="2" 
onkeydown="if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) { submit(); }"></textarea>
```

> **Replace the submit function with the code that submit your form.**

*I hope this answer your question. If this was not the question you needed answer or not the answer you wanted please leave a comment so I can edit my code accordingly.*

Comment: Thanks! I have to wait until Friday with checking that. But what I already know is that Enter works in Chrome but not in IE. So it might be some browser related problem. But I will test your idea Ryan